# Ratio test cancellation when applied to $\sum n 7^n/(n+2)!$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am having trouble canceling out numbers using the ratio test. I got the denominator correct but I don't see how the numerator is not 7.

[image]

Comment: There is a missing $(n+1)/n$ term.

Comment: Where do I plug it in?

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\left\lvert\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right\rvert = \left\lvert \frac{(n+1)7^{n+1}}{(n+3)!} \frac{(n+2)!}{n7^{n}}\right\rvert = \left\lvert \frac{(n+1)7}{n(n+3)}\right\rvert.$$

I presume the limit is easy for you compute from here.